# Dependant T-SQL comparison collation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

Is there any way to set the collation for a string comparison based on an independent variable or column value?  Something akin to

```
SELECT COL1, col2
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE COL3 LIKE '%string%'
    COLLATE CASE CASE_SENSITIVE 
                WHEN 1 THEN SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
                ELSE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
            END
```

or

```
DECLARE @collation AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @collation = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' 

SELECT COL1, col2
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE COL3 LIKE '%string%'
    COLLATE @collation
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along the lines of this with 2 where conditions.

One will be become `'%string%' LIKE '%string%'` which is always true

```
WHERE
    CASE WHEN @casesenstive = 1 THEN COL3 ELSE '%string%' END
           COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS LIKE '%string%'
    AND
    CASE WHEN @casesenstive = 0 THEN COL3 ELSE '%string%' END
           COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%string%'
```

Comment: Nice one.  Great for a binary condition, but is there any way to switch collation on a variable to accommodate several collations, accent sensitivity, case, etc other than doing nested case statements?

Comment: @laramie: no, sorry. it's "hard coded"